# touchscreen not working under Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, kde, touch-screen, plasma5, wacom

I pulled out an older Lenovo ThinkPad with a touchscreen (X220 tablet, Core i7) which had been running Ubuntu and I installed Arch Linux on it. Everything is fine except the touch screen does not work. It did work under the older version of Ubuntu I had installed (12.04).

I check several posts, but not find a solution yet. Here are some of the better resources I found:

[Wacom Touchscreen on ThinkPad X220 Tablet Has Disappeared / Kernel & Hardware / Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=148073)

[kernel 3.5.3-1 breaks wacom tablet on X220T [WORKAROUND] / Kernel & Hardware / Arch Linux Forums](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=147887)

[Touchscreen - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchscreen)

Here is the relevant info on this machine. The touchscreen is Wacom.

less /proc/bus/input/devices

```
I: Bus=0003 Vendor=056a Product=0090 Version=0110
N: Name="Wacom ISDv4 90 Pen"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.5/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0/0003:056A:0090.0001/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event4 mouse0
B: PROP=2
B: EV=b
B: KEY=1c03 0 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=1000003

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=000a Version=0000
N: Name="TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint"
P: Phys=synaptics-pt/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/serio2/input/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event18 mouse2
B: PROP=21
B: EV=7
B: KEY=70000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3
```

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 056a:0090 Wacom Co., Ltd TPC90

# lsmod | grep wacom
wacom                 114688  0
usbhid                 57344  1 wacom
hid                   139264  3 hid_generic,usbhid,wacom
led_class              16384  5 sdhci,wacom,input_leds,thinkpad_acpi,iwldvm
```

dmesg | grep "[w|W]acom"

```
[    5.403690] input: Wacom ISDv4 90 Pen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0/0003:056A:0090.0001/input/input7
[    5.403775] wacom 0003:056A:0090.0001: hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Tablet ISD-V4] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.5/input0

# ls /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.5/2-1.5:1.0/0003:056A:0090.0001/input/input7
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root    0 Jun 10 17:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Jun 10 17:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Jun 10 17:05 capabilities
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun 10 17:20 device -> ../../../0003:056A:0090.0001
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Jun 10 17:05 event4
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Jun 10 17:05 id
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 17:20 modalias
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Jun 10 17:05 mouse0
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 17:20 name
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 17:20 phys
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Jun 10 17:20 power
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 17:20 properties
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Jun 10 17:05 subsystem -> ../../../../../../../../../../class/input
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 17:20 uevent
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Jun 10 17:20 uniq
#
```

pacman -Qi xf86-input-libinput

```
Name            : xf86-input-libinput
Version         : 0.27.1-1
Description     : Generic input driver for the X.Org server based on libinput
Architecture    : x86_64
URL             : http://xorg.freedesktop.org/
Licenses        : custom
Groups          : xorg-drivers
Provides        : None
Depends On      : libinput>=1.2.0
Optional Deps   : None
Required By     : xorg-server
Optional For    : None
Conflicts With  : xorg-server<1.19.0  X-ABI-XINPUT_VERSION<24  X-ABI-XINPUT_VERSION>=25
Replaces        : None
Installed Size  : 87.00 KiB
Packager        : Laurent Carlier
Build Date      : Tue 10 Apr 2018 12:14:20 PM EDT
Install Date    : Sat 21 Apr 2018 10:38:04 PM EDT
Install Reason  : Installed as a dependency for another package
Install Script  : No
Validated By    : Signature
```

libinput list-devices

```
Device:           Wacom ISDv4 90 Pen
Kernel:           /dev/input/event4
Group:            7
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             262x163mm
Capabilities:     tablet
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      n/a
Nat.scrolling:    n/a
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      identity matrix
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   none
Rotation:         n/a
```

modinfo wacom

```
filename:       /lib/modules/4.16.8-1-ARCH/kernel/drivers/hid/wacom.ko.xz
license:        GPL
description:    USB Wacom tablet driver
author:         Vojtech Pavlik <vojtech@ucw.cz>
version:        v2.00
srcversion:     B48B4FFD10AA0DCD3863653
alias:          hid:b0005g0101v0000056Ap*
alias:          hid:b0018g0101v0000056Ap*
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap*
alias:          hid:b0003g*v000017EFp00006004
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00005002
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00005000
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00004004
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00004001
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000037B
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000037A
alias:          hid:b0005g0101v0000056Ap00000361
alias:          hid:b0005g0101v0000056Ap00000360
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000343
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000033E
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000033D
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000033C
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000033B
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000336
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000335
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000333
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000331
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000032F
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000032C
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000032B
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000032A
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000326
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000325
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000323
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000319
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000318
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000317
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000315
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000314
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000030E
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000030C
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000030A
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000309
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000307
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000304
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000303
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000302
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000301
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000300
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000012C
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000116
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000010F
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000010E
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000010D
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000101
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000100
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000FB
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000FA
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000F8
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000F6
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000F4
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000F0
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000EF
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000ED
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000EC
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000E6
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000E5
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000E3
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000E2
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000DF
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000DE
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000DD
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000DB
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000DA
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000D8
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000D7
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000D6
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000D5
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000D4
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000D3
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000D2
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000D1
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000D0
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000CE
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000CC
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000C7
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000C6
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000C5
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000C4
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000C2
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000C0
alias:          hid:b0005g0101v0000056Ap000000BD
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000BC
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000BB
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000BA
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000B9
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000B8
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000B7
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000B5
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000B4
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000B3
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000B2
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000B1
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap000000B0
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000009F
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000009A
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000097
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000093
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000090
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000084
alias:          hid:b0005g0101v0000056Ap00000081
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000006B
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000006A
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000069
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000065
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000064
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000063
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000062
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000061
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000060
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000005E
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000005D
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000005B
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000059
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000057
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000047
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000045
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000044
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000043
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000042
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000041
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000003F
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000039
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000038
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000037
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000035
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000034
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000033
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000032
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000031
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000030
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap0000002A
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000029
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000028
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000027
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000026
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000024
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000023
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000022
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000021
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000020
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000019
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000018
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000017
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000016
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000015
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000014
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000013
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000012
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000011
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000010
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000003
alias:          hid:b0003g0101v0000056Ap00000000
depends:        hid,usbhid,led-class
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           wacom
vermagic:       4.16.8-1-ARCH SMP preempt mod_unload modversions 
parm:           touch_arbitration: on (Y) off (N) (bool)
```

xsetwacom --list devices

```
Wacom ISDv4 90 Pen stylus               id: 10  type: STYLUS
Wacom ISDv4 90 Pen eraser               id: 15  type: ERASER
```

It should look more like this example from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wacom_tablet

```
Wacom Bamboo 2FG 4x5 Pen stylus     id: 8   type: STYLUS
Wacom Bamboo 2FG 4x5 Pen eraser     id: 9   type: ERASER
Wacom Bamboo 2FG 4x5 Finger touch   id: 13  type: TOUCH
Wacom Bamboo 2FG 4x5 Finger pad     id: 14  type: PAD
```

Linux 4.16.8-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed May 9 11:25:02 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux

cat /dev/input/event4

```
No output while touching screen
```

Comment: Were you able to fix this problem or workaround it? I'm experiencing similar things as you are with a Lenovo x60 running Manjaro XFCE. Quite frustrating and makes me think of trying to install XP.

Comment: @Erik - see https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=239175

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be my problem. Appreciate the help, though.